# Byte Array to Double in C#

Tags: c#, double, arrays, converters

I have a program set up that reads a double value into byte array using C#.
The value is set to 1.0 but the byte array result I get is 63 and 128.

for example:

```
 Byte[] array; // gets result
      //result I get...
   the 0th value - 63
   the 1st value - 128
```

How do I convert these values back to double (1.0)?

Comment: How do you convert double to byte array? where is your code?

Comment: [2 bytes is a bit short of a double.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I don't know who marked you down, or why.  But yours is a fair question.  And Sergei Zhukov gave you the correct answer: [BitConverter.ToDouble()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  NOTE: Make sure you generated the array correctly, e.g. with [BitConverter.GetBytes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5be4sc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Your array should definitely have more than two bytes.

Comment: The rest is zero. 1 is 3FF0 0000 0000 0000

Comment: And it seems you use `float` instead of double. BitConverter.GetBytes would give 240 and 63 for double(padded with zeros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BitConverter.ToDouble(array, 0);
```

P.S. it will work if you used something like

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(1.0)
```

to pack double into array. I can't understand what do you mean by 0th value and 1st value? If your byte array contains only two bytes - it's not double.

Comment: I get 1.62 E-319 as the converted value.

Comment: then stored value in your byte array is not a double. What is the size of the array?

Comment: It was using a float value not double.